# ZendServer installing PEAR on Windows. could not extract the package.xml file

Tags: windows, powershell, installation, pear, zend-server

The first thing I did was to modify security on "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR" giving myself and the system as well as application installers full control. I open a PowerShell windows as Administrator and run the following "php go-pear.phar". I get output as follows:

```
            PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR> php go-pear.phar

            Are you installing a system-wide PEAR or a local copy?
            (system|local) [system] :

            Below is a suggested file layout for your new PEAR installation.  To
            change individual locations, type the number in front of the
            directory.  Type 'all' to change all of them or simply press Enter to
            accept these locations.

             1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR
             2. Temporary directory for processing            : C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\tmp
             3. Temporary directory for downloads             : C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\tmp
             4. Binaries directory                            : C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR
             5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\pear
             6. Documentation directory                       : C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\docs
             7. Data directory                                : C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\data
             8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\cfg
             9. Public Web Files directory                    : C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\www
            10. Tests directory                               : C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\tests
            11. Name of configuration file                    : C:\WINDOWS\pear.ini
            12. Path to CLI php.exe                           : C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin

            1-12, 'all' or Enter to continue:
            Beginning install...
            Configuration written to C:\WINDOWS\pear.ini...
            Initialized registry...
            Preparing to install...
            installing phar://C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/bin/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Archive_Tar-1.3.7.tar...
            installing phar://C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/bin/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Console_Getopt-1.3.0.tar...
            installing phar://C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/bin/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/PEAR-1.9.4.tar...
            installing phar://C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/bin/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tar...
            installing phar://C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/bin/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/XML_Util-1.2.1.tar...
            could not extract the package.xml file from "phar://C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/bin/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Archive_Tar-1.3.7.tar"
            could not extract the package.xml file from "phar://C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/bin/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Console_Getopt-1.3.0.tar"
            could not extract the package.xml file from "phar://C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/bin/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/PEAR-1.9.4.tar"
            could not extract the package.xml file from "phar://C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/bin/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tar"
            could not extract the package.xml file from "phar://C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/bin/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/XML_Util-1.2.1.tar"
            install failed
            PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR>
```

I'm on Zend Sever CE 5.6 on Windows 8.1. The error seems to be "could not extract the package.xml file".

Thank you for posting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this issue. Here is how i have been able to fix it.

I renamed go-pear.phar to go-pear.phar.old and downloaded the go-pear.phar from the pear website:

http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

and I  ran it as :

php go-pear.phar

And everything went fine. There is of course some issue with the one that Zend provided.